# Power BI regional settings

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, dax

I have the following problem:
I changed the regional settings to Dutch. This means that number should have the following format: ###.###,## ,and currencies should have the following: 
€###.###,##

unfortunately this doesn't seem to work (see picture/table in the background) when I do the DAX formatting it doesn't change it to the European format but to the American format.

[image]

can anyone help me understand why this doesn't effect my report? I am running the latest version but couldn't find the solution to my problem online. I've tried almost every solution given by Microsoft but non work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Locale for import** settings only affect imports from untyped data sources e.g. text files.

The locale used for display is set when the PBIX file is created, based on the windows settings of the machine.  It can't be changed through the UI, but there is this workaround you could try:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/changing-the-culture-of-a-power-bi-desktop-file/

Comment: By doing this I have to change the file to a PBit. afther that this wouldn't have any effect on the reports and data connections I have?

Cause I found this solution earlier but I have to work around a lot of things because I can't Install that tool on my server (security issues)

Comment: I can't know what your exact reports and data setup is, but usually this is fine - as long as you end up with a PBIX file with the same name. Before you save a PBIT as a PBIX, it will need to re-run all your Queries to reload all your tables. That's a good practise anyway before publishing.

Comment: Thanks Mike i'll try that and see if it helps me :)